# T-SQL Get 3 Month Interval : Trying to count Property_IDs over a close_dt Interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to count Property_IDs over a close_dt Interval

```
select distinct pd.state AS StateName, zw.CountyName AS [County Name]
,sum(case when pc.close_dt >= dateName(MM,dateadd(MM,-3,GetDate()))then 1 
else 0 end) AS [0-3 Months]
,sum(case when pc.close_dt >= dateName(MM,dateadd(MM,-6,GetDate())) 
                and pc.close_dt < dateName(MM,dateadd(MM,-3,GetDate())) then 
1 else 0 end) AS [3-6 Months]  
 from resnet_mysql.dbo.property_details pd (Nolock)
join resnet.dbo.ZipCodesView zw (nolock)
    on CAST(LEFT(pd.zip, 5) AS varchar) = CAST(zw.ZipCodeID AS varchar)
join resnet_mysql.dbo.property_closings pc (nolock)
    on pd.property_id = pc.property_id
group by pd.state, zw.countyName, pc.close_dt
```

How can I get the 3 month interval from the previous 3 month interval value? So it will be 3-6 months?

I want it to look like this.

[image]

But I get this error.

[image]

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: Why would you be trying to compare a *date* to the name of a month?

Comment: oh dang. I'm trying to convert MYSQL to T_SQL. THe MySQL code looks like.

Comment: SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND
 pc.close_dt < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS  `3-6 Months`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking you want something like this:

```
select pd.state AS StateName, zw.CountyName AS [County Name],
       sum(case when pc.close_dt >= dateadd(month, -3, GetDate()) then 1 
                else 0
           end) AS [0-3 Months]
       sum(case when pc.close_dt >= dateadd(month, -6, GetDate()) and
                     pc.close_dt < dateadd(month, -3, GetDate())
                then 1
                else 0
           end) AS [3-6 Months]  
from resnet_mysql.dbo.property_details pd join
     resnet.dbo.ZipCodesView zw 
     on LEFT(pd.zip, 5) = CAST(zw.ZipCodeID as VARCHAR(5)) join
     resnet_mysql.dbo.property_closings pc 
     on pd.property_id = pc.property_id
group by pd.state, zw.countyName;
```

Your original code has so many errors, it is hard to list them:

- `DATENAME()` returns a string.  Why would you want to compare that to a date?
- You are aggregating based on date ranges.  You don't want to include the date in the `GROUP BY`.
- `LEFT()` already returns a string; there is no need to convert it.
- You probably don't want to compare a string version of zip code to a numeric id.  But if you do, the conversion should specify the length.
- `WITH (NOLOCK)` is not recommended unless you actually know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks so much. Gosh I cant even think straight with the flu(cough + sore throat)